# Cloudant Lucene boost factor during indexing

Tags: search, lucene, cloudant

During indexing time it is possible to set a boost factor value which then changes the position of specific record in the array of returned documents.

Example:
index("default", doc.my_field, {"index": "analyzed", "boost": doc.boostFactor});

When applying this boost factor I can see that the sorting changes. However, it appears to be rather random.
I would expect a number greater than 1 would sort the document higher.

Did anybody managed to get the boost factor with Cloudant to work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Cloudant boost factor should work correctly. Setting `boost` to a field of a specific doc, will modify the score of this doc: `Score = OriginalScore * boost` while searching on this field.

Do you search on the same field you boost? How does your query look like?  Does the field `my_field` consists of multiple tokens? This may also influence scoring (e.g. longer fields get scored less).

You can observe scores of docs in the `order` fields in the results, and then by modifying `boost` observe how the scores are changing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: We pre-calculate a boostfactor value for every document.

Our initial calculation was based on a value between 1 and 20 where 20 should receive the highest boost.
However, when applying it we noticed that the factor influences the order but some of our 20s were sorted lower than without the boost factor.
For some other search results it worked as expected so overall it appeared to be random.
We also tried different levels (1 to 10, 1 to 100 etc.) but with similar results.

We tested in a restricted db to avoid external changes to the db.

Comment: The field with the boost factor can be searched directly but that's usually not the case.

Comment: Yes, if you are searching on several fields, these other fields may influence the scoring (Lucene scoring formula: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html).

Comment: If you need your docs to be sorted by some field `boostFactor`, you can just add this field to the index, and then sort the results by this field, and if needed also by relevance `"sort" :["boostFactor","<score>"]`

Comment: Our test was performed with single words against the default index to have the best way to compare results And of course sorting wouldn't solved the problem of a wrong boost factor.